# How do I pass parameters as JSON format to the HTTP client request?

Tags: 8, http-request

How can I pass parameters to the http client get request in json format:

```
$clientFactory = \Drupal::service('http_client_factory');
$client = $clientFactory->fromOptions(['verify' => FALSE]);

$params = '{"data1":"",
"data2":"mydata"
"data3":"mydata",
"data3":"mydata",
"data5":"mydata"}';

$url = 'https://myendpointurl';
try {
  $response = $client->get($url, array(
      'headers' => array('Accept' => 'text/plain'),
    )
  );
  $data = json_decode($response->getBody());
}
catch (RequestException $e) {
  watchdog_exception('my_module', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Where I need to put `$params` variable in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the request like so:

```
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
...
$response = $client->get($url, [
    'headers' => ['Accept' => 'text/plain'],
    'json' => Json::decode($params),
]);
```

Comment: what's the advantage of using `Json::decode($params),` over `json_decode`?